# sp_executesql is making my dynamic query run MUCH slower

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a query written in two ways. Once like this:

```
declare @var1 int
declare @var2 int


set @var1 = 1
set @var2 = 50

declare @myQuery = nvarchar(max)
set @myQuery = 'INSERT INTO someTable
                @var1
                WHERE something = @var2'

EXEC sp_executesql @myQuery,
    N'@var1 int,
    @var2 int',
```

I also have the query as:

```
declare @var1 int
declare @var2 int   
set @var1 = 1
set @var2 = 50

INSERT INTO someTable
@var1
WHERE something = @var2
```

My real query is much much longer and complicated. The first way takes about 4 minutes, while the second way takes about 20 seconds. What is going on!? I've been trying to research similar issues, and I keep seeing things about query caching, but usually it's because people aren't doing it the first way, they're just doing exec on a nvarchar.

I'm pretty inexperienced with SQL and completely lost. Any help would be great.

The reason I'm doing it the first way is that I'm calling a stored procedure from C# and passing it in parameters.

Comment: In these scenarios the issue often exists in the comlexity of the query being run due to parameter sniffing. You can also sometimes run into issues where implicit converting causes certain indexes to not be used. The point being it could be various things, but without a more accurate representation of the complexity you're only going to get random guesses and conjectures. To answer this question you need to provide the query and related schema objects within the query.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using SSMS, there's an option to show the execution plan of the query. Take a look at that and see what's different in each case.

I'm confused by your reason for doing the first way...is the sp_executesql part of your stored proc? Or are you just trying to emulate a stored proc from SSMS?

Comment: The actual stored procedure generates some dynamic SQL from the input parameters, puts it into a nvarchar, then uses sp_executesql on the final string.